# Why does microtype affect the spacing of custom sections when using titlesec?

Tags: spacing, titlesec, microtype

In LuaLaTeX, I have the following code that allows for me to have a section that is not numbered, and that has the text centered, with smallcaps font style on. I thought the text looked a but not on the centered, and i tried to test out if i was just seeing it wrong, and yes, i was correct. When `{\centering\textsc{Problem 1.}\par}` and `\begin{center}\textsc{Problem 1.}\end{center}` are typed, they result in something that is spaced differently from `\section{Problem 1.}`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\scshape\centering} % format
    {} % label % replace with {\thesection. } if need the section number on sections.
    {0cm} % sep
    {} % before-code
    \titlespacing*{\section}
    {0cm} % left
    {0cm} % before
    {0cm} % after

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textsc{Problem 1.}
\end{center}

{\centering\textsc{Problem 1.}\par}

\section{Problem 1.}

\end{document}
```

The culprit is the `microtype` package, as when taking it away, it will have `{\centering\textsc{Problem 1.}\par}` and `\begin{center}\textsc{Problem 1.}\end{center}` be the same as `\section{Problem 1.}`. It seems that `microtype` adds unnecessary space to those two, and I'm not sure why.

Can anyone provide any insight on this, or any way to fix this and make it correctly adjusted? it would be a big help.

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct to say that "the culprit is the `microtype` package". For sure, if I replace your `titlesec`-based formatting instructions with `\usepackage{sectsty}` and `\sectionfont{\centering\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}`, then `\section*{Problem 1.}` has no problem with centering.

Comment: Off-topic: it really isn't a good idea to remove all the stretch in vertical spacing around section titles. It's not just that the defaults introduce vertical space. They also include flexible space which helps TeX break pages in good places. If you remove that, you'll generally get poorer results.

Comment: @Mico It is some sort of interaction, I guess, since removing `microtype` also gets correct alignment. But I'm more than happy to blame `titlesec` ;).

Comment: a one-off solution would be to insert the protrusion manually: `\section{Problem 1\rightprotrusion{.}}`

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the problem is with `titlesec`'s insertion of `struts` to keep some vertical distances consistent.

If you insist on using `titlesec`, a possible fix (if it really bothers you and doesn't upset spacings) could be the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\nostruts\scshape\filcenter} % format
{} % label % replace with {\thesection. } if need the section number on sections.
{0cm} % sep
{} % before-code
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0cm} % left
{0cm} % before
{0cm} % after

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
        \textsc{Problem 1.}
    \end{center}
    
    {\centering\textsc{Problem 1.}\par}
    
    \section{Problem 1.}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: With `\usepackage[nostruts]{titlesec}` one globally disables struts.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative which achieves the section format you want without `titlesec` and, so, avoids the problem.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textsc{Problem 1.}
\end{center}

{\centering\textsc{Problem 1.}\par}

\section{Problem 1.}

\end{document}
```

[image: three unproblematic problems]